# Import MS Visual Foxpro .dbf tables into MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, foxpro, dbf

Does anyone know how to import .dbf file into MS ACcess 2007?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do this programmatically?

MS-Access has option to import the tables OR you could create a Linked Table.

EDIT: Open the MS-Access MDB, goto tables. Right click -> Import -> Choose the appropriate database type (could be dbf in your case).

Comment: how do i import the tables form the MS ACCESS option? Please explain more... thanks

Comment: In A2007, it's on the ribbon under EXTERNAL DATA. Click the MORE dropdown and DBF is one of the choices.

Comment: there are tons of tools around, I used this one to convert my files http://www.whiterocksoftware.com/2019/03/dbf-to-mdb.html?q=dbf%20to%20mdb

Answer (score 0):

Well a VBA approach to pragmatically pull this information is to create a connection object connecting to the directory of the tables you want to pull from.

After that open a recordset to query what you need from the tables against that connection.  A big benefit of directly connecting and scanning is that your not bulking up tables in your database to push you closer to your next repair/compact.

In order to get this connection however I needed some kind of ODBC connector, something the network admins came and installed behind my back when I switched to a new work PC and it suddenly broke upon connection.  If this is something you would be using on other users PCs who won't have access to this (if this is a query you will be performing on a normal basis) it may not function properly for others...

Comment: Er, the VBA approach would be to use TransferDatabase to import each DBF file in turn.